# Music player / database for read-only music collection

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am looking for a music player and/or database for using with a *read only* music library.

**The situation is this:**

- I have a music library (FLACs, OGGs, MP3s) that I, for diverse reasons, want to keep *read-only and not change at all* (apart from adding more files...).
- A few of the files are not tagged at all and some files are badly tagged.

**Features I look for**

- A music player with an external ‘tag’ database. That is, the tags are saved separate from the audio files and override information found in the audio files.
- The database should be initialized form the tags in the files, but subsequent edits should (as per the previous point) be visible in the program, but *not* written to the audio files. The program should never even attempt to write to the audio files.
- Import/export function for tag data would be appreciated.

  - *Situation:* The audio files are on a network drive and I want to synchronize the database between the computers that mount the net-drive.
- Convert-feature would also be appreciated. Where a selected subset of the audio files would be re-encoded (for example, into low-bitrate OGG Vorbis for use on my phone) and would be put *outside* the collection and automatically be tagged with the information in the database.

**Also,**

- Searching or playing by artist/genre/year/... is *not* a required feature. (see next point)
- I use playlists; so managing playlists and adding from the present folder structure is a wanted feature.

**So,** is there any program fulfilling (most of) these points?

Or, could someone point me towards a solution for this situation? I am not too averse to some scripting and such...

Answer (score 0):

Try [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the [m-TAGS](http://m-tags.org/foobar2000_component.html) plugin. It is a Windows program, but [runs reasonably well](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1749) with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

Comment: Thanks. I know of foobar2000 (I used to use it on Win, and tried it on Ubuntu some years ago). I will investigate the m-TAGS format.